# Попап при смене ориентации экрана сбивается с центра

Tags: ios, swift

Есть попап. Я его создал не как View, а как ViewController
Если открыть изначально в горизонтальном режиме то норм, если изначально в вертикальном режиме тоже норм. А вот если ориентацию меняю "походу" при открытом попапы то он сбивается с центра. Вот на скринах примеры:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Затем сразу же меняю ориентацию

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот StoryBoard

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот как я открываю ПОПАП :

```
                let storyBoardPopupBaner = UIStoryboard(name: "BanerPopupStoryboard", bundle: nil)
                let popupVC : BanerPopupView  = storyBoardPopupBaner.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BanerPopupView") as! BanerPopupView
                popupVC.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
                popupVC.modalTransitionStyle = .coverVertical
                rootVC.present(popupVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

то есть есть два ViewController'a  попап я открываю поверх новостного ViewController'a

выделил вот так и сделал как вы сказали
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbkdY.png)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

почему красный квадрат у меня не полностью залит, а у вас полностью?

Comment: Приложите пожалуйста новый проект с элементами из основного чтобы воспроизвести эту ошибку.

Comment: @VAndrJ https://github.com/muaviya/PopupTest.git Запустите пожалуйста в планшетном режиме и смените ориентацию экрана.

Comment: Создал пулл реквест с фиксом

Comment: @VAndrJ получил вашу версию все хорошо, хотел заюзать у себя, но почему то красный квадрат не заливается, обновил ответ со скринами, гляньте пожалуйста. Спасибо.

Comment: Присмотритесь к стрелочкам внутри квадрата, они у Вас пунктирные.

Comment: @VAndrJ да, они снутри не тапаются. по идее снутри должны тапаться верно ?

Comment: Вот тут не подскажу, т.к. никогда этим не пользовался, у меня тоже не тапается. Поэтому подправил в Source code сториборда, а не в интерфейс билдере

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в том, что у Вас не авторесайзится view:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Должно быть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое!